# Replace IIS certificate in IIS version 6.1

Tags: certificate, iis-6

I wanted to change a certificate, the certificate is in an IIS v6.1.

I went to IIS management console and issued a new Certificate Request, the certification autority then elaborated my request and sent me back 4 files crt.

lets say that the certificate is name.domain.com.crt

I installed the 3 files in the server and then completed the crt request selecting the name.domain.com.crt file.

At this point if i go in IIS i can se the new name.domain.com certificate in the certificate section.

But if I reach https://name.domain.com site I get the old certificate.

What should I check to fix it?

how can i force the site https://name.domain.com to use the certificate I want?

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager, set the appropriate binding (right column) for the desired site.